# How to remove warning message about funs() is deprecated in dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr

I have this warning message when I use this script
I think I have to use a list instead of funs() ?

```
library(dplyr)

result <- iris %>% 
  count(Species) %>% 
  bind_rows(summarise_all(., funs(if(is.numeric(.)) sum(.) else "Total")))
```

Warning message:
`funs()` is deprecated as of dplyr 0.8.0.

Many thanks in advance !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`across` is the current way to summarize/mutate multiple columns (since `dplyr` version 1.0). And we also use `purrr`-style anonymous functions with `~`.

```
iris %>% count(Species) %>%
  bind_rows(summarize(., across(everything(), ~if(is.numeric(.)) sum(.) else "Total")))
#      Species   n
# 1     setosa  50
# 2 versicolor  50
# 3  virginica  50
# 4      Total 150
```

Comment: Perfect ! Thanks a lot ! I will accept the answer !

Answer (score 2):

You can wrap your call in `suppressWarnings` to prevent warnings from being posted (i.e. "remove" them).  *However*, doing so will not address any underlying issue(s) which caused the warning in the first place.

Better practice would be to note the warning and attempt to fix the code such that a warning isn't generated at all.  Several other folks have posted answers doing exactly this.

```
suppressWarnings(
result <- iris %>% 
    count(Species) %>% 
    bind_rows(summarise_all(., funs(if(is.numeric(.)) sum(.) else "Total"))))
```

Comment: Thanks but if I think it's better if I'll do with a list

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
library(dplyr)

result <- iris %>% 
    count(Species) %>% 
    bind_rows(summarise_all(., list(function(x) if(is.numeric(x)) sum(x) else "Total")))
```